# Dropping of 2 balls (though the center of Earth)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets

If 2 balls with equal mass are dropped into 2 separate tube of which one passes through the center of the Earth and the other passes adjacent to it, which ball will come out first if both balls are dropped simultaneously? Assume no friction or drag. Assume uniform density. Assume Earth doesn't rotate.

Comment: 1.  are the tops and bottoms of the tubes equidistant from the central plane though which they pass, or are they each flush with the surface at their respective locations?  2. Can we consider the density of the Earth to be uniform?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am sure that always the first will be the faster, independently from the parameters (Earth radius, density distribution and so on), but this comment is unfortunately too small to show my wonderful, simple proof for that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, (Suppose the holes are in pole to pole direction to avoid crashing into walls due to rotational speed) the ball through the center of the earth will come out first. If I am not wrong, after 24 minutes if you ignore the air resistance.

The other ball will likely touch the side of the tube that is towards the center of the earth. This would result into friction to slow down the ball.

If you also consider friction less tube, or the tube to be wide enough (and close enough to center), that the ball does not touch the side within 24 minutes, then same time for both the balls.

Comment: For the first part of your A both balls shall crash to the wall by virtue of their tangential speed at surface. Better think of frictionless pipe "something like pneumatic post" able to drive the ball according to g.

Comment: @Alchimista: Thanks for the correction, totally missed the rotation, though may not apply on pole to pole hole. I will better delete the answer in a bit.

Comment: Correct . Pole to pole should not matter.  However meantime I doubt of the second part as well. If a semorbit take 24 min a shorter one shall take less. Ergo the second ball should come out first.... right?

Comment: @Alchimista: I did not do calcs, but based upon my memory, it does not matter where to where, it is always same time through the tunnels.

Comment: Yes true. Acc and length compensate.

Comment: @Alchimista: I added to the answer "pole to pole" context based upon your comment.

Comment: How big are the balls and tubes relative to the size of earth. Also, in any frame, one must consider the center of mass.